# Login to Jboss 7.1.1 Final admin console with Java

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

I need to login into Jboss admin console using a Java program. I have searched for a whole day but didn't find a single clue about how to do it. I tries using HttpClient 4.0 , but , it ended which error : "Unexpected end of File".
Please upload any code fragment if you have . Or may be, there should be any configuration which should be there in Jboss server itself. Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you log in to a human UI from a Java application? It would make more sense to log in to JBoss's JMX endpoint, because that is a machine interface.

Comment: Actually my requirement is to create a app which will monitor jboss memory usage in unix server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to know is the memory usage of the JBoss process than I think the easiest way is to ssh to the server and use normal unix commands to get the answer, e.g. here is a way of getting the process ID of JBoss and then passing it to the pmap command which supposedly gives you the memory usage (I cannot confirm that because MacOS doesn't have pmap, but Linux has):

```
ps -ax | grep "JBoss" | grep -v grep | awk '{print "pmap " $1}' | sh
```

If you really want to connect to JBoss to get information then JMX is the way to go. JBoss provides the facility to connect via RMI and query all the MBeans. See [this chapter](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r1/html/ch2.chapter.html), section 2.3.2 on how to connect to JBoss JMX.